# MacBook Pro 13 (early 2015) with 4K Television: Can I get 60Hz?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport, 4k

The TV has only HDMI inputs. I've found cables on the Internet that will connect Mini DisplayPort to HDMI: [AmazonBasics Mini DisplayPort to HDMI Cable - 3 Feet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0134V29UA)

My question is, will I get 60Hz when doing Mini DisplayPort to HDMI? Currently I'm using the HDMI port on my MBP and I'm only getting 30Hz on this TV. I've heard that using the mini DisplayPort will get you 60Hz, but I'm not sure if that still holds true when the other end of the cable is HDMI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The cable that you listed does not support 4K.**  In fact, on the description page, it specifically states the following:

> Supports video resolutions up to up to 1920x1200 and 1080p (Full HD);
>   easy-grip

If you are going to convert a signal from one to another (mDP to HDMI in this case) you need an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271) like the [Plugable Active Mini DisplayPort to HDMI 2.0 Adapter](http://radnex.us/plugable-mdp-hdmi-active-4K)