# 2017 15" MBP & UHD TV: 4k60Hz *very* intermittent

Tags: display, hdmi, resolution, 4k

I have the MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017), a Samsung 4k display, and a USB-C to HDMI cable between them (plugged directly into the computer).

The entire setup supports everything necessary. Please don't say they need to be compatible.

After a lot of fiddling, I get it to do 4k@60Hz and it works perfectly - even piped the audio.

Then, something will happen - power flicker, I turn off/on the TV, take my laptop somewhere else, act of god occurs, whatever - and the computer will suddenly forget it can use 4k@60Hz.

Sometimes this is fixed by repeatedly unplugging/plugging-in the display, most times not.

I have the command-line utility `screenresolution`. Sometimes OS-X decides to use 30Hz **even when it knows 60Hz is available**. This utility can then change it for me.

Sometimes (like right now) I want to throw this computer off the roof because it refuses to believe it supports 4k@60Hz.

This is independent of OS-X version, independent of TV (this same issue happened with a TCL TV), and independent of cable (happened with a different brand of cable).

I tried some system-preferences extension which required me to turn off SIP to manually add custom modes, and that sometimes worked - but also sometimes caused the HDMI audio to not work, so I got rid of that.

**How do I convince OS X that the monitor does and always will support 4k @ 60Hz?**

In case it matters, I also have (on a different USB-C port) a USB-C/TB3 hub and its display-port output goes to the MDP-to-dual-link-dvi-adatper to a 30" Cinema Display, so I have the 4k@60Hz TV, the 30" Cinema Display, and the laptops display all acting as non-mirrored monitors.

This is the [active] cable I’m using:  [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B075V5JK36/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_3g9hBbY6VM4X5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075V5JK36)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MacBook Pro 13 (early 2015) with 4K Television: Can I get 60Hz?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297195/macbook-pro-13-early-2015-with-4k-television-can-i-get-60hz)

Comment: The issue here, as in the linked dupe, is that you need to use an active adapter; not a cable that converts the signal.  This is KEY when using things like HDMI (which is horribly flaky to begin with)

Comment: @allan No, this is not a duplicate. This IS an active adapter, and it DOES work - but sometimes OS-X doesn’t agree. If the problem were the wire being non-active, it wouldn’t ever work. But it does. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B075V5JK36/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_3g9hBbY6VM4X5

Comment: There's nothing on that page that says it's active.  An active adapter is very different from a passive adapter.  See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271

Comment: The HDMI end of the cable is large and quite hot, indicating there is an active chip there.

Comment: Ok, I just tried an adapter advertising itself as being an active adapter supporting 4k@60Hz - same problem (no 60Hz)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but with a MacBook 13" 2017, a Samsung 4K TV, and a USB-C to HDMI 2.0 active cable.

**How to solve the problem:**
First connect the USB-C end of the cable to the MacBook, then after a couple of seconds connect the HDMI end to the TV while powered on. I got 100% success in having 4K @ 60hz using this procedure.

**How is this possible:**
Not too technical, but... The active chip on the cable's HDMI end first powers up and initializes from connecting it to the USB-C port, and in sequence, the correct resolutions and refresh rates are offered as soon as the other end of the cable is connected to the TV.

I know this is not a proper solution, but at least it doesn't make me want to throw the MacBook out of the window!

I hope there's some more feedback from other users.